# How can I create multiple buttons with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am looking for a way to create a row of buttons in kivy. I am fairly new to kivy so this is what I came up with.

My current code is:

```
class StackGameApp(App):

  def build(self):

    layout = FloatLayout()

    b0 = Button(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '0')
    b1 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .1, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '1')
    b2 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .2, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '2')
    b3 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .3, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '3')
    b4 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .4, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '4')
    b5 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .5, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '5')
    b6 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .6, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '6')
    b7 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .7, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '7')
    b8 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .8, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '8')
    b9 = Button(pos_hint={'x': .9, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '9')
    layout.add_widget(b0)
    layout.add_widget(b1)
    layout.add_widget(b2)
    layout.add_widget(b3)
    layout.add_widget(b4)
    layout.add_widget(b5)
    layout.add_widget(b6)
    layout.add_widget(b7)
    layout.add_widget(b8)
    layout.add_widget(b9)
    return layout
```

Which returns a row of buttons at the bottom of the screen labeled 0-9. I will be coding the buttons to return the numbers 0-9, but that hasn't been done yet.

I am almost certain there is a better, easier way of doing this but i just don't know what it is.

Comment: Do you know what `for` loop is?

Comment: for x in 10:

            i = Button(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'center_y': .1}, size_hint=(.1, .1),text= '0',)

            i.bind(on_press=user_input)

            layout.add_widget(i)

            i+=1
Error int is not iterable

Comment: I strongly suggest you doing some basic python course before using kivy. Learn how to use lists, dicts, loops, functions, classes, etc.

Comment: That is super helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely learn the basics of loops first like jligeza mentioned, but essentially, you need to do something along the following lines:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    layout.add_widget(Button(text=str(i))
```

Note that the reason that you were getting an error with your `for x in 10` comment is because just as the error says an integer is not iterable. Instead, if you use range(0,10), what this is doing is it is iterating through the following **list**: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`